# Настройка плагина jquery mask

Tags: jquery

Помогите настроить плагин `jquery mask` для номера телефона таким образом, чтобы маска состояла из набора `+7 (495) ...` (остальное вводит пользователь). По умолчанию цифра `9` используется для того, чтобы обозначить место для цифры (может быть введена любая цифра):

```
mask('+7 (999) 999-99-99')
=
+7 (___) ___-__-__//Это будет отображаться в input
```

То есть, такое не сработает:

```
mask('+7 (495) 999-99-99')
=
+7 (4_5) ___-__-__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.mask.definitions['9'] = '';
 $.mask.definitions['n'] = '[0-9]';
 $('.fallback').mask('+7 (495) nnn-nn-nn');
```